# Child component doesn't rerender but parent component does rerender. How to make child component rerender?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Parent component does rerender upon receiving new props but its child component doesn't rerender. Child components only render for the first time and never rerender nor receive props from the redux store

I'm getting updated data from redux store in Parent component but not in the child components. Child components only receive data from redux store when they render for the first time

My Parent Component `Home.js`

Object seaFCLJSON look like this
`const seaFCLJSON ={"rates": {"sort":"faster", "someOther": "someOtherValues"}};`

when the redux store gets updated, seaFCLJSON looks like this
`const seaFCLJSON ={"rates": {"sort":"cheaper","someOther": "someOtherValues"}};`

```
class Home extends Component {
state = {
    seaFCLJSON: {}
  };

componentDidMount = () => {
     this.setState({ seaFCLJSON: this.props.seaFCLJSON });
  };

 componentWillReceiveProps = nextProps => {
    if (this.state.seaFCLJSON !== nextProps.seaFCLJSON) {
      this.setState({ seaFCLJSON: nextProps.seaFCLJSON });
    }
  };

 render() {
    const { seaFCLJSON } = this.props;
 return (
       <>
    {!isEmpty(seaFCLJSON) && seaFCLJSON.rates && seaFCLJSON.rates.fcl ? (
          <FCLContainer fclJSON={seaFCLJSON} />
        ) : null} //it never rerenders upon getting updated data from redux store

    <h5>{JSON.stringify(seaFCLJSON.rates && seaFCLJSON.rates.sort)}</h5> //it rerenders everytime upon getting updated data from redux store
       </>
     );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    seaFCLJSON: state.route.seaFCLJSON
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  actions
)(Home);
```

`isEmpty.js`

```
export const isEmpty = obj => {
  return Object.entries(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object;
};
```

My Child Component `FCLContainer.js`

```
class FCLContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    seaFCLJSON: {}
  };
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({ seaFCLJSON: this.props.seaFCLJSON });
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps = nextProps => {
    console.log("outside state value: ", this.state.seaFCLJSON);
    if (this.state.seaFCLJSON !== nextProps.seaFCLJSON) {
      this.setState({ seaFCLJSON: nextProps.seaFCLJSON });
      console.log("inside state value: ", this.state.seaFCLJSON);
    }
  };


  render() {
    const { seaFCLJSON } = this.state;
    console.log("rendering .. parent props: ", this.props.fclJSON);
    console.log("rendering .. redux store props: ", this.props.seaFCLJSON);

    return (
      <>
        <div className="home-result-container">
          <div>
          <h5>This child component never rerenders :(</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    seaFCLJSON: state.route.seaFCLJSON
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  actions
)(FCLContainer);
```

I don't know whether there are problems in Parent component or problems in the child component. `componentWillReceiveProps` gets invoked in the parent component but not in the child component. Please ignore any missing semi-colon or braces because I have omitted some unnecessary codes. 
Edit 1: I just duplicated value from props to state just for debugging purposes.

I will appreciate your help. Thank you.

**Edit 2**: I was directly changing an object in redux actions. That's the reason CWRP was not getting fired. It was the problem. For more check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillReceiveProps` will be deprecated in react 17, use `componentDidUpdate` instead, which is invoked immediately after updating occurs
Try something like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.prevProps.seaFCLJSON !== this.props.seaFCLJSON) {
      this.setState({ seaFCLJSON: this.props.seaFCLJSON });
    }
  };
```

Comment: I tried it. It didn't solve my issue. It didn't get invoked. It only gets invoked for the first time and never gets invoked for updated props

Comment: @blueseal are you able to create a code sandbox with the code?

Comment: sorry I tried to reproduce it but could not, later abandoned it because my project was huge.

Answer (score 0):

At the first place it is absolutely meaningless to duplicate value from props to state, what is the meaning of it? Totally pointless, just keep it in props

About your issue - most probably this condition doesnt match, thats why child component doesnt trigger

```
!isEmpty(seaFCLJSON) && seaFCLJSON.rates && seaFCLJSON.rates.fcl
```

check it in debugger

Comment: It's already late in the night. I will try it tomorrow and let you know .. thank you!

Comment: I just duplicated value from props to state just for debugging purposes. ```if(!isEmpty(seaFCLJSON) && seaFCLJSON.rates && seaFCLJSON.rates.fcl){ console.log("everything is otay");}``` it does output "everything is otay" to console

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your problem is that you pass the following to your child component:

```
<FCLContainer fclJSON={seaFCLJSON} />
```

But you assume that you receive a prop called 'seaFCLJSON':

```
 componentDidMount = () => {
this.setState({ seaFCLJSON: this.props.seaFCLJSON });
```

};

You should change your code to:

```
<FCLContainer seaFCLJSON={seaFCLJSON} />
```

Apart from that, as @Paul McLoughlin already mentioned, you should use the prop directly instead of adding it to your state.

Comment: I don't need to pass any props to my child component from the parent, because I get the updated values from the redux store (only for the first render). I just passed prop ```fclJSON``` to child component for debugging purposes. I don't know why child component doesn't receive updated data from the redux store

Comment: I am able to get updated props from the parent in the child component. But any idea why the child is not getting updated data from the redux store but parent is getting the same? In my real projects, Child components do have their own child components so I should avoid props-drilling.

Comment: As far as I know, `componentWillReceiveProps` will not be called if this.setState is used to modify the state or if the component is mounted. If your rendering condition (for whatever reason) in the parent component changes from true to false and back again, the component is remounted and `componentWillReceiveProps` is never called. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Also I would remove all the logging code any simply pass the data from the parent to the child (not connecting the child to the redux state) and make sure to render some of the props in the children.

Comment: Well have you got a repository or something like that? It should actually be a quite easy case but I feel like I'm missing some information.

As long as the Store provider wraps those components it should bot be a problem to connect from children.

Comment: I removed the rendering condition from the parent component and moved it to the child component. But still, I'm not getting updated data from store. I will try a little more debugging then I will let you know and probably invite you to my repo. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Ok, let me know how it went. Sure if you invite me I'll have a look into it. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue I was directly mutating the object in actions. I only knew `state` should not be directly mutated in `class` or inside `reducer`. I changed the actions where I was directly changing an object and then saving it in redux store via `dispatch` and, then I received the updated props in CWRP. This really took me a lot of times to figure out. This kind of issue is hard to find out at least for me. I guess I get this from https://github.com/uberVU/react-guide/issues/17

A lesson I learned: **Never directly mutate an Object**

**I changed this**

```
//FCL sort by faster
export const sortByFasterFCLJSON = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  let seaFCLJSON = getState().route.seaFCLJSON;
  if (!seaFCLJSON.rates) return;
  seaFCLJSON.rates.fcl = _.orderBy(
    seaFCLJSON.rates.fcl,
    ["transit_time"],
    ["asc"]
  );

  seaFCLJSON.rates.sort = "Faster"; //this is the main culprit

  dispatch({ type: SET_SEA_FCL_JSON, payload: seaFCLJSON });
};
```

**to this**

```
//FCL sort by faster
export const sortByFasterFCLJSON = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  let seaFCLJSON = getState().route.seaFCLJSON;
  if (!seaFCLJSON.rates) return;
  seaFCLJSON.rates.fcl = _.orderBy(
    seaFCLJSON.rates.fcl,
    ["transit_time"],
    ["asc"]
  );

  // seaFCLJSON.rates.sort = "Faster"; //this was the main culprit, got lost

  seaFCLJSON = {
    ...seaFCLJSON,
    rates: { ...seaFCLJSON.rates, sort: "Faster" }
  };

  dispatch({ type: SET_SEA_FCL_JSON, payload: seaFCLJSON });
};
```

[the power of not mutating data](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data)

Side note: [Redux Troubleshooting](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md)